# Integrating expo-segment with facebook app event is not working

Tags: react-native, facebook, expo, segment, event-tracking

I am trying to track the app events using expo-segments but the events do not get added in facebook events manager even though the destination in Segment has been configured according to the documentation. I am unable to find any solution online as well.

Comment: Have you found a solution or a reason for this?

Comment: No, I didn't find any solution for it.